# 'Incorrect Systax Near'R05' Expecting HOLDLOCK or ID, Tengo una duda mySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy diseñando un procedure, en Sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertReserve(@code char, @fecha date , @hora int , @lugar varchar, @cancha varchar, @cliente varchar, @trabajador int,@estado varchar, @precio decimal) as 
begin 
    if exists (select 1 from Reserve where DateReserve = @fecha and StartTime = @hora) begin
        select 'ya existe la hora en la fecha' problema
    end
    else begin
        insert into Reserve
        values(@code,@fecha,@hora,@lugar,@cancha,@cliente,@trabajador,@estado,@precio)
    end 

end  
go
```

Basicamente, lo que intento es que si dentro de mi base de datos, tengo
`R01`, `2022-06-01`, `4` , `C01`, `T02`, `75930013`, `1`, `'Bien'`, `20`

Si registro otro
`R02`, `2022-06-01`, `4` , `C01`, `T02`, `75930013`, `1`, `'Bien'`, `20`.

Si esta es la misma fecha, el `startTime`, osea el 4 en este caso, debe ser diferente ya que el 4, ya esta registrado en esta fecha.

Coloco esto, para confirmar

```
InsertReserve('R05','2022-06-20',10,'C01','T01','75930013',1,'Sin Confirmar',0.00)
```

Me aparece error en R05, apareciendo lo del titulo

Comment: ¿Cuál es la estructura de tu tabla? ¿No tienes antes del campo `code` un id autonumérico o algo así? Cuando insertas en la tabla sin especificar campos, han de corresponderse tal cual los valores que le pasas y en el mismo orden, además, lo que quizá a veces genera problemas cuando después se cambia la estructura de la misma

Comment: Esa es sintaxis de T-SQL, en MySQL no es igual.